Could the Axiom of Choice be viewed as a restricted version of the Axiom of Union?
Given the ZFC Axiom of Union in the form :
$$\forall x \exists y \forall z (z \in y \iff \exists w (z \in w \land w \in x)) $$
or consider :
$$\forall x \exists y \text{ ("separate" every element ... from each element w in x and put it in y)} \tag{1}$$
Given the ZFC Axiom of choice in the form :
$$\forall x \exists y \forall z (z \in y \iff \exists w (z \in w \land w \in x \land \text{(only one element from w is in y}))) $$
or consider :
$$\forall x \exists y \text{ ("separate" only one element ... from each element w in x and put it in y)} \tag{2}$$
The intent of the wording "separate" in (1) and (2) is to indicate that the Axiom Schema of Separation would 'ideally' be used, were it powerful enough to be 'available' whatever the number of times it is simultaneously needed. The objective would be to embody the, maybe not unreasonable ability, that every set could be simultaneously distinguished (i.e. 'separated') from every other set in a "universe of sets".
Question :
Could the Axiom of Choice be considered to be a restricted version of the Axiom of Union, under the assumption that the Axiom of Separation be made sufficiently powerful ("Super Separation"), to embody the ability to be able to simultaneously distinguish/separate every set from every other set in some "universe of sets"? Or would this lead to Russell type paradoxes and we have to accept that some sets are just too complex to be able to simultaneously distinguish between them ?

The ZFC Axiom of choice in not equivalent to
$$\forall x \exists y \forall z (z \in y \iff \exists w (z \in w \land w \in x \land \text{(only one element from w is in y}))).$$

@Anne Bauval. OK - but its very close, I can expand it out to be exact, but I thought that would detract. Do you have a suggestion ?

@Anne Bauval.  From wiki - In the non empty disjoint elements case it looks like the change would be to include w $\cap$ y  :
$$\forall x \exists y \forall z (z \in y \iff \exists w (z \in w \land w \in x \land \text{(only one element from w is in w $\cap$ y})))$$

What is from (which) wiki? Anyway: 'only one element from w is in w∩y' is equivalent to the previous 'only one element from w is in y', and
$$\forall x \exists y \forall z (z \in y\impliedby\exists w (z \in w \land w \in x \land \text{(only one element from w is in y})))$$is false. Take for instance $x={{a,b}}$. I don't find your statement 'very close' to AC, and I have no suggestion to make your post sensible.

@Anne Bauval. Wow, what a subtle catch. Embarrassingly the formula presented: $ \forall x \exists y \forall z (z \in y \iff \exists w (z \in w \land w \in x \land \text{(only one element from w is in y})))$ looks to produce only empty choice set solutions. There is a simple fix though and if you agree the change needed is to replace "only one element from w is in y" by "z is the only element from w in y", I can then edit the equation to apply to the pairwise disjoint elements version of AC. It will not affect the question meaning since only (1) and (2) were subsequently used.

With this replacement, $\impliedby$ becomes always true, so your new formula is equivalent to$$\forall x\exists y(\forall z\in y)(\exists w\in x)\quad w\cap y={z}$$ which is still not equivalent to AC, because $y=\varnothing$ is a solution.

If by "Can the Axiom of Choice be phrased as 'given a family of sets, there is a subset of their union with a certain property'?", then the answer is yes, with a qualified yes. Namely, it's not true that there is transversal from every family of sets, but rather we need to require the family is pairwise disjoint. Otherwise, consider $\{\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$. Any transversal must select both $0$ and $1$ from their respective singletons, but then cannot select exactly one element from $\{0,1\}$.
But the Axiom of Choice is not somehow "separating something from the union", since we are not separating anything. Separation requires some kind of a property, whereas the transversal simply exists and is not required to have any kind of property other than being a transversal.
In the formal sense, the Axiom of Choice does not follow from $\sf ZF$, so it is not somehow a restricted form of the Axiom of Union, even in the presence of Separation.
One can evolve your question into asking if it is somehow a combination of the Axioms of Union and Power Set, since we're talking about some subset of the union, rather than separating it, it is simply an element of the power set. But, again, this is inaccurate.
It is a good thing to see the Axiom of Choice as its own entity. To understand it best, here's a way I found fruitful to view this situation. The axioms of $\sf ZF$ tells us one of three things: Extensionality tells us what equality and membership have to do with each other; Infinity tells us that some sets exist; the rest of the axioms tells us that given a set $X$ we can build another set in a definable and specific way, and that by applying Extensionality, that set is in fact unique.
So, the axioms of $\sf ZF$, really, define constants and operations on sets. That is, the least inductive set is a constant; the union operation; the power set operation; the "range" or "image" operation; the subset-given-by-a-property operation; etc.
In contrast to all of that, the Axiom of Choice does not define anything. It is a blackbox of existential statement. Indeed, if $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a family of pairwise disjoint non-empty sets which are not singletons, then there are a lot of different transversal sets. Which one is "the" transversal? There is no preference here, there is no uniqueness. It's only existence.
We can, of course, add additional axioms, such as Gödel's $V=L$, which allow us to define a "preferred transversal" in a uniform way. But the axioms of $\sf ZFC$ are not sufficient for proving that there is a definable operation which picks a transversal from every family of pairwise disjoint non-empty sets.
